# setInterval not working as expected with javascript oops

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, setinterval

Js Fiddle : [check here](https://jsfiddle.net/svinesh3691/6e0mg97k/)

I have setInterval() inside a method of a class. It works properly when single instance is created but fails when many instance created. When more than one instance created , only the last created instance work and other stops.

My script is as below :

```
function timer() {
    this.ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    this.cls = this.ran + '_ocar';
    this.div = '<div class="' + this.cls + '">' + this.cls + '</div>';
    $('body').append(this.div);
    this.run = function() {
        thi = this;
        thi.k = 0;
        setInterval(function() {
            console.log(thi.cls);
            $('.' + thi.cls).html(thi.k++);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
one = new timer();
one.run();
setInterval(function() {
    new timer().run();
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`thi = this;` is being created in the global namespace, so is being overwritten each time you initialise a `new timer()`.

Change it to `var thi = this;`.

https://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/h5e8LLg3/`

I don't like `thi` as a var name - it looks like a typo. I usually use `_this` or `_scope`.

Comment: What do u mean @ Jai ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function timer(){
    var thi = this;
    this.ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    this.cls =  this.ran+'_ocar';
    this.div = '<div class="'+this.cls+'">'+this.cls+'</div>';
    $('body').append(this.div);
    this.run = function(){

       thi.k = 0;
       setInterval(function(){
         console.log(thi.cls);
         $('.'+thi.cls).html(thi.k++);
      },1000);
   }
}
one = new timer();
one.run();
setInterval(function(){
  new timer().run();
},5000)
```

Your variable `thi` need to be declared locally and moved.